# ScrollView starts to low and crops content

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

I have a `BottomNavigation` **Activity**, one of my activities is a scroll view, here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Test"/>
        </TableRow>
        ...
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Test"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see, the `ScrollView` doesn't start at the top.
In addition, the content is cropped by the same amount of space lost at the top.

This seems like an easy problem, has anyone an Idea?

[image: Screenshot]

By demand: the activity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_activities, R.id.navigation_logs)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

And the `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The LayoutInspector output:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you also add Activity code? Another thing: instead of ```android:layout_height="wrap_content"``` in your TableLayout use ```android:layout_height="match_parent"```

Comment: You can use the [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to find out which component is actually occupying the white space at the top.

Comment: @EfeBudak changing the height did nothing, the activity code does nothing currently, added it anyways.

Comment: @danzel It seems that the navigation bar is drawn before the scroll view and then pushed down later, without the scroll view being pushed up, any idea how to fix that?
(Screenshot provided in post)

Comment: Can you try android:layout_height="0dp" for nav_host_fragment?

Comment: @EfeBudak didn't change anything, changing the height of nav_view removed the navbar but the scroll view was still the same distance from the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, the was solution:
Delete `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`. 
You must also add `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` at `nav_host_fragment` so that the view is not below the BottomNavigationView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is actually better than the previously accepted answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute in the container:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Probably a good idea to change it to:

```
  android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: I haven't even thought of changing that file, it was generated by android studio. removing `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` was enough, though there is still something missing at the end (i can get rid of that problem by adding `android:paddingBottom="60dp"` to my table) Thank You!